# Wordpress directory permissions and PHP 8.2

Tags: php, shared-hosting, php-8.2, directory-permissions

I am running a Wordpress installation (6.4.3) on a shared hosting server.

Uploading media files, and applications requiring access to the wp-content folder, works fine on PHP 8.1

However if I upgrade to PHP 8.2 (and 8.3) and try to upload a file then I get the error message:

"The uploaded file could not be moved to wp-content/uploads/"

I am aware that this is usually a directory permissions issue, but as far as I can see (using FTP) there is no change to permissions (755 for both wp-content and uploads).

Can anyone suggest why this should be so only on PHP 8.2, and what can I ask the hosting provider to check since I have no root access?

Apologies if this is not the correct forum on which to ask my question.

I have loaded a fresh blank Wordpress installation on the hosting server and get the same problem.

I have cloned the original site to another shared hosting provider and the problem does not appear.

So the issue seems to be with the hosting provider. I have raised a support ticket but so far the issue remains unresolved. I cannot change provider since I have inherited this site. Thank you.

Update:
I have been informed by the hosting company that this is a problem with PHP 8.2 (and 8.3) on Litespeed servers running under cPanel. I am advised to continue running PHP 8.1 until it is resolved.